# How to run API calls in Vuetify dialog only when the dialog is shown?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a dialog in Vuetify that needs some API calls to fill in the view. I'd like to *not* run those heavyweight API calls when the main screen loads (`onMounted`), but only when the dialog is first shown (and ideally shut down my API listener when the dialog is closed). But I can't find any way to do that. I looked at [v-intersect](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/intersect/) but it looks complicated and error-prone, and not available on IE. Is there any event fired by Vue or Vuetify, or a reactive value set, when a dialog is shown?

I'm using Vue 2 with the composition-api, if that's helpful.

Here's a short version of the RenderDialog component (just the script part):

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'RenderDialog',
  setup(props, context) {
    const state = reactive({
      dialogValue: 0,
      expensiveComputationResult: 0,
    })

    watchEffect(async () => {
      state.expensiveComputationResult = await doExpensiveComputation(state.dialogValue)
    })

    return {state}
  }
})
```

and here's how it's called from the parent:

```html
          <render-dialog>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn v-on="on">Open Dialog</v-btn>
            </template>
          </render-dialog>
```

Right now, it calls `doExpensiveComputation` every time the page loads. I want to defer that until the user opens the dialog.

Comment: `v-model` (`value`)+ `watch`

Comment: @AndrewShmig can you explain more? What is `value` there?

Comment: could you share the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim added some context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did in a similar situation — a small explanation of **AndrewShmig**'s comment:

```html
<template>
  ...
  <v-dialog v-model="dialogVisible">
    ...
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    ...
    data() {
      return {
        ...
        dialogVisible: false,
        requiredData: null, // expensive to load
      }
    },
    watch: {
      dialogVisible(newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal && this.requiredData === null) {
          this.doLoadTheData()
        }
      },
    },
    ...
  }
</script>
```